# Why is a null sequence in $L^p(M)$ also a null sequence in $\mathscr{C}^p_k(M)$?

Tags: riemannian-geometry, smooth-manifolds, sobolev-spaces

I am currently reading "Nonlinear analysis on manifolds: Sobolev spaces and inequalities" from Emmanuel Hebey and on page 21, he introduces the Sobolev spaces on Riemannian manifolds. For reference, here's the page my question is about:

> Let $(M,g)$ be a Riemannian manifold. For $k$ an integer and $u\in C^\infty(M)$, $\nabla^ku$ denotes the k-th derivative of $u$ (with the convention $\nabla^0 u =u$). As an example, the components of $\nabla u$ in local coordinates are given by $(\nabla u)_i = \partial _i u$, while the components of $\nabla^2 u$ in local coordinates are given by
> $$(\nabla^2 u)_{ij} = \partial_{ij} u - \Gamma^k_{ij} \partial _k u.$$
> By definition one has that
> $$|\nabla^k u|^2 = g^{i_1j_1} \ldots g^{i_kj_k} (\nabla^k u)_{i_1\ldots i_k} (\nabla ^k u)_{j_1\ldots j_k}.$$
> For $k$ an integer and $p\geq 1$ real, we denote by $\mathscr{C}^p_k(M)$ the space of smooth functions on $u\in C^\infty(M)$ such that $|\nabla^j u| \in L^p(M)$ for any $j=0, \ldots, k$. Hence,
> $$\mathscr{C}^p_k(M) = \left \{u\in C^\infty(M) \text{  s. t. } \forall j=0,\ldots, k, \int _M |\nabla^j u|^p dv(g) < \infty  \right\}$$
> where, in local coordinates, $dv(g) = \sqrt{\det(g_{ij})}dx$, and where $dx$ stands for the Lebesgue's volume element of $\mathbb{R}^n, n = \dim M$. If $M$ is compact, one has that $\mathscr{C}^p_k(M) = C^\infty (M)$ for all $k$ and $p\geq 1$. $$ \ $$
> **Definition 2.1:** *The Sobolev space $H^p_k(M)$ is the completion of $\mathscr{C}^p_k(M)$ with respect to the norm*
> $$\| u\|_{H^p_k} = \sum _{j=0}^k \left (\int _M |\nabla^j u|^p dv(g) \right)^{1/p}$$
> Noting that a Cauchy sequence in $\mathscr{C}^p_k(M)$ is also a Cauchy sequence in $L^p(M)$, and that a Cauchy sequence in $\mathscr{C}^p_k(M)$ which converges to $0$ in $L^p(M)$ converges to $0$ in $\mathscr{C}^p_k(M)$, the Sobolev spaces $H^p_k(M)$ can be seen as subspaces of $L^p(M)$.

I'm having trouble proving the last statement

> $\ldots $ and that a Cauchy sequence in $\mathscr{C}^p_k(M)$ which converges to $0$ in $L^p(M)$ converges to $0$ in $\mathscr{C}^p_k(M)\ldots$

Basically what needs to be proven is that if we have given a Cauchy sequence $u_n$ in $\mathscr{C}^p_k(M)$ with $u_n \to 0$ in $L^p(M)$, then $\| |\nabla^j u| \|_p \to 0$ for $j=0,\ldots k$, where the case $j=0$ is just the convergence in $L^p(M)$.

**My approach:** The functions $ |\nabla^j u_n|$ converge in $L^p(M)$ as
$$ \|u\|_{H^p_k} \geq \| |\nabla^j u|\|_p.$$
I then tried to somehow multiply the quantity $|\nabla^j u_n|$ by a test function, integrate by parts and go to the limit, as it was done in one of the answers [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2189141/if-f-n-to0-in-l2-and-the-derivatives-converge-in-l2-must-the-limit-be). However, I just can't get it to work. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I'm really not an expert, but reading only the title (and the definition of $\mathscr C_k^p $), the statement  has no sense since in $L^p$ you have equality a.e. whereas in $\mathscr C_k^p $ the equality is everywhere.

Comment: you seem to be ignoring the fact that it's a **Cauchy sequence**...

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich It is a Cauchy sequence, however the space $\mathscr{C}^p_k(M)$ is not a complete space regarding the $\|\cdot \|_{H^p_k}$ norm (which is why we defined the Sobolev space as the completion of $\mathscr{C}^p_k(M)$). Or am I overlooking something obvious?

Comment: @Surb Yes, I agree. I think this has to be understood in the way that we regard $\mathscr{C}^p_k(M)$ as a subset of $L^p(M)$, i.e. all equivalence classes (in the $L^p$ sense) of smooth functions with the first $k$ derivatives being bounded in $L^p$)

Comment: I'm not familiar with the manifold case, so I'm sorry if this is dumb, but if you work in local coordinates what happens? Even in the Euclidean case it's not a trivial matter to prove that a definition like yours gives a unique gradient (in the case $k=1$) when you're dealing with weighted Sobolev spaces (which is kind of what you have here, though there's also the issue of the extra terms like $\Gamma_{ij}^k\partial_k u$ that are throwing me off).

Comment: @Jose27 Well, I don't think we have a "weighted" Sobolev space here. Let's suppose for a second that our manifold is some compact subset in $\mathbb{R}^n$, then there's a theorem that says the space is independent of the Riemannian metric we choose (which defines the inner product on the tangent space). So we can just choose the inner product from $\mathbb{R}^n$ restricted to the tangent space.
The covariant derivative $\nabla_i$ basically is the normal gradient, projected onto the tangent space. In the case of $\nabla _i u$, where $\nabla_i$ acts on a function $u$, it is just the normal ...

Comment: ... derivative which lies in the tangent space. If we try to differentiate a tensor field like $\nabla_i\nabla_i u$, then this derivative may lie outside of the tangent space due to the curvature of the manifold, which is why in this case we have the extra terms $\Gamma^k_{ij} \partial _k u$, which subtracts the part normal to the tangent space... at least that's what I understood

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me sketch an argument that should work but I haven't checked all the details. Let's concentrate on the case $k = 1$. The basic idea is to use integration by parts, only we have to do it globally on the manifold without resorting to local charts (which defeats the point of Hebey's definition).

Since $(u_k)$ is Cauchy in $\mathscr{C}^p_1(M)$, $|\nabla u_k|$ is Cauchy in $L^p(M)$ so $\nabla u_k$ converges to some $L^p$ vector field $X$ in $L^p$. We need to show that $X = 0$. Choose an arbitrary compactly supported smooth vector field $Z$ on $M$. Then using integration of parts we have:

$$ \left| \int_{M} \left< X, Z \right> \, dv(g) \right| = \left| \int_{M} \left< X - \nabla u_k + \nabla u_k, Z \right> \, dv(g) \right| \leq \\
\left| \int_{M} \left< X - \nabla u_k, Z \right> \, dv(g) \right| + \left| \int_{M} \left< \nabla u_k, Z \right> \, dv(g) \right| \leq \\
\int_{M} \left| X - \nabla u_k \right| \cdot |Z| \, dv(g) + \left| -\int_{M} u_k \, \operatorname{div} Z \, dv(g) \right| \leq \\
\int_{M} \left| X - \nabla u_k \right| \cdot |Z| \, dv(g) + \int_{M} |u_k| \left| \operatorname{div} Z \right| \, dv(g) \leq \\ \| \left| X - \nabla u_k \right| \|_{L^p} \| \left| Z \right| \|_{L^q} + \|u_k\|_{L^p} \| \operatorname{div} Z \|_{L^q}
$$

where $q$ is the conjugate exponent to $p$. Note that the integration of parts is applied only to $\nabla u_k$ and $Z$ which are both smooth and not to $X$. Both terms on the right-hand side are finite (as $Z$ has compact support) and tend to zero so we get that

$$ \int_{M} \left< X, Z \right> \, dv(g) = 0 $$

for all compactly supported $Z$ which implies that $X = 0$.

One should do the case $k > 1$ similarly using an integration by parts formula for higher order tensors (see for example page 29 in these [lecture notes](https://www.math.uci.edu/%7Ejviaclov/courses/865_Fall_2016.pdf)).

Comment: That's a very clever argument! I have one more question though, why did we need a subsequence of $\nabla u_k$ for the $L^p$-convergence to $X$ instead of using the sequence itself?

Comment: @Pengin: Your absolutely correct, we don't. I'll edit my answer. BTW, this is just a translation of the usual "integration by parts" argument to the global setting. There are various details to check and fill (one needs the $L^p$ space of vector fields, to verify that if the norm of a sequence of vector fields is Cauchy then the sequence converges to some $L^p$ vector field, etc).

Comment: I think I have a working definition of the $L^p$ space for vector fields. We choose all equivalence classes of vector fields $X$ on $M$, such that 
1. The components of $X$ in any chart are measurable functions 
2. $\langle X,X\rangle \in L^p(M)$.
with $\|X\| := \| |X|\|_p$. Equipped with the equivalence relation $X\sim Y$ if $\|X-Y\|=0$, this is (or rather I believe it is, I don't have a proof) a Banach space.

Comment: This definition extends to (covariant) tensor fields of any order, using the inner product on tensor fields $\langle S,T\rangle = g^{i_1j_1} \cdot \ldots \cdot g^{i_k j_k} S_{i_1\ldots i_k} T_{j_1\ldots j_k}$.

Comment: @Pengin: You want to require only that $|X| = \sqrt{ \left< X, X \right>} \in L^p(M)$. See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2064539/on-a-manifold-is-the-lp-space-of-vector-fields-complete.